# SQL invalid identifier in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

My database diagram...

https://s13.postimg.org/4rqz9purr/image.jpg

I need to list the name of each officer who has reported more than the average number of crimes officers have reported.

Here is my SQL...

```
SELECT 
    last, first
FROM 
    officers 
JOIN 
    crime_officers USING (officer_id) 
JOIN 
    crimes USING (crime_id)
JOIN 
    crime_charges USING (crime_id)
WHERE 
    crime_charges > ALL (SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) FROM crime_charges);
```

However, I am getting this error:

> invalid identifier on line 6 "crime_charges"

Comment: Either you PK on your diagram is bad (0/1,N) or your `crime_officers` table should not exist (0/1,1)...

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this error is that, right into the `WHERE` clause, you used a table name (`crime_charges`) instead of a single expression. You should replace it by an expression which computes the number of crimes reported by an officer:

```
WHERE number_of_crimes_reported_by_an_officer >ALL (SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) FROM crime_charges) ;
```

But getting deeper into your problem, you are still far from the right solution. If the requested result is a set of officers, your query **should browse directly the officers table** (with no other joins), adding the proper conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT last, first
FROM officers
WHERE (compute_number_of_crimes_reported_by_an_officer) >ALL (SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) FROM crime_charges) ;
```

See? In this way, you'll get a list of **officers**. Instead, if you add joins to related tables, the number of records will be unnecessary multiplied.

Comment: Now I am even more confused. :(

Comment: I recommend you to proceed step by step: First, code a query which computes the number of crimes reported by each officer: `SELECT last, first, number_of_crimes FROM officers`. Then, add the requested condition into a `WHERE` clause (which you already have got): The global average number of crimes.

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems off.  To get the average number of crimes per officer (that has reported a crime):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT officer_id) 
FROM crime_officers ;
```

To get the officers that have more than the average, use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select co.officer_id
from crime_officers co
group by co.officer_id
having count(*) > (select count(*) / count(distinct officer_id)
                   from crime_officers
                  );
```

You can use additional `JOIN`s to bring in additional columns.

EDIT:

It is not so hard to get the officers's names:

```
select co.officer_id, o.last, o.first
from crime_officers co join
     officers o
     on co.officer_id = o.officer_id
group by co.officer_id, o.last, o.first
having count(*) > (select count(*) / count(distinct officer_id)
                   from crime_officers
                  );
```

Comment: `SELECT co.officer_id, co.last, co.first` if you just want  to bring the full name (no join for these two)

Comment: But I need the name, not the officer id

Comment: @codeRed as I just said, `SELECT co.last, co.first` should even work too

Comment: and the last and first names are not in the crime_officers table

Comment: @codeRed my bad, read too fast, use `SELECT co.officer_id, o.last, o.first` and add `JOIN officer o ON officer.officer_id = co.Officer_id` between the `FROM` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: @codeRed got it, forgot the `S` in `officers` : `JOIN officers o ON o.officer_id = co.officer_id`

Comment: @codeRed edit your post and put some data for the main table; I can't anything without this...

Comment: data for the main table?